# Chart Sharepoint list data with Google Visualization using REST API

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, visualization

I have the following json data from our Sharepoint Server and I am trying to use Google charts to generate a pie chart and barchart:

I have 4 teams for which I need to create a separate pie chart. For each pie chart, I need to: 
1) count the number of all open task by team;
2) count the number of past due tasks by Team. To achieve this I am thinking of checking if the due date is past then count the total number the past due tasks by Team and show on the chart,
3) Count the total number of tasks that are due in 7 days from today by team.

Finally Bar chart
4) Generate a bar chart for all the 4 teams with the average task duration

So far I am able to pull the data from the server and show some basic piechart, which is not in the format that I need. 
I need help with with group the different elements of the list item by TeamName when producing the pie chart per team.

I have spent many days trying to solve this without success.

My data from our SharePoint list looks like below:

```
{
    "d":
    {
        "results":
        [
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'0000-000-0000-3344-afret4532')/Items(11)",
                    "uri": "https://myserver/home/siteDev/_api/Web/Lists(guid'0000-000-0000-3344-afret4532')/Items(11)",
                    "etag": ""22"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TasksDevelopment"
                },
                "Team": "Team, (TE-08)",
                "TaskName": "Task1",
                "DueDate": "2014-04-25T04:00:00Z",
                "Status": "Closed",
                "Created": "2014-02-24T05:00:00Z",
                "DateClosed": "2014-04-17T04:00:00Z",
                "TaskDuration": "18",
                "PastDueDate": "2014-04-26T04:00:00Z"
            },


Here is my current REST code that I am using and it is from the following blog post: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/justguy/2013/05/22/google-charts-pie-2-with-angularjs-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest/



   $scope.loadREST = function () {

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "https://myserver/home/siteDev/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Teams')/Items?$filter=TaskStatus eq 'Open'&$select=TeamName,Task_Duration",
       type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "true",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var newData = [];
            jQuery.each(data.d.results, function(index,value) {
                newData.push([value.TeamName, value.Task_Duration]);
            });
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.chartData = newData;
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
};
```